# Increase body width to fit content

Tags: html, css, width

I want a HTML page with a border around the content. The content does not fit on the screen.

Example:

```
<div style="border: solid red 1px;">
    <div style="width: 2000px;">
        Hello world
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like the bordered DIV to be 2000 pixels wide. However, it is only as wide as the browser viewport.

How can I make the outer DIV as wide as its contents, preferably without Javascript?

Comment: I'm a little unclear in reading your question. Why wouldn't you just `Width: 100%` on the outter `DIV`

Comment: It would maker more sense if you'd set the width on the outer DIV.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make the outer `<div>` shrink to fit its contents ("shrinkwrap") by adding `float: left`.

Comment: In this case it would be "expandwrap".

Answer (score 2):

Just float it.

```
 <div style="border: solid red 1px; float: left;">
        <div style="width: 2000px;">
            Hello world
        </div>
    </div>
```